# Why "to" is dropped after "is"?

Tags: to-infinitive

Why is 'to' sometimes dropped in these kinds of sentences?

> What you want to do **is make** a plan

There's no 'to' between 'is' and 'make'.

> The next thing you want to do **is to stay** in the present moment.

There is 'to' between 'is' and 'stay'.

***Similar example***

> The first thing you need to do ***is to trim*** vegetables.
>
> The first thing you need to do ***is trim*** vegetables

Comment: I may be wrong, but _'what you wanna do is make a plan'_ sounds colloquial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is a case of the ["zero infinitive"](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/infinitive/).

Essentially, either usage is correct, though there may be a preference for the zero infinitive case ("The first thing you need to do is trim vegetables"). Using the to-infinitive case ("The first thing you need to do is to trim the vegetables") tends to sound unnecessarily formal.