# Does the expression ( is rewrite) correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

I found the following sentence in my Mathematics book.

> All we need to do is rewrite it.

I knew that *rewrite* is a verb. In that sentence, is *rewrite* a noun or an adjective.

Comment: You say that rewrite is a verb and then ask if it is a noun or adjective?? Very odd.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why "to" is dropped after "is"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93693/why-to-is-dropped-after-is) Also [all you need to do is figure out - if "figure out" is changed to "to figure out", how does the meaning change?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29365/) and [Is the sentence 'What I need is to do/doing the things I like.' grammatically correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/), among others. In your example, ***rewrite*** is a "bare infinitive verb" (*without* the optional infinitive marker ***to***).

Comment: [Is X correct? No does]

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence, 'rewrite' is a verb (as it usually is), denoting the action that is *all we need* to perform (the only action we need to perform, usually to complete some task).

An expression of the type *All that I/you/we need to is...* must be followed by a verb in the bare- or to-infinitive form.

I have cooked the bacon. All I need to do is **fry** the eggs.

After we have dug the hole, all we need to do is **to throw** the dead dog in.

'To do' is optional. and can be omitted, provide the to-infinitive form of the following verb is used:

To complete the cake, after icing or ('frosting') all you need is **to place** a cherry on the top.

Comment: Actually, the _to_ infinitive would also be possible in all these cases: "All we need to do is to rewrite it".

Comment: @ColinFine Why bother repeating the to function word?

Comment: Because people do. The WOW corpus has 39 instances of _all * need to do is VERB_ and 7 of _all * need to do is to VERB_.